# Array Print Well but Undefined index when access array index in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an import script in laravel. $row values print well like **Result 1** and when I want to print it's index like **Result 2** errors come. how can I access $row index like $row['email'] here?

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$csvData = file_get_contents($file);
$rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));
$header = array_shift($rows);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if (count($header) != count($row)) {
        continue;
    }
    $row = array_combine($header, $row);
    dd($row);//result1
    dd($row['email'];//result2
}
```

**Result1:**

```
array:1 [▼
  "﻿email" => "info@businesswithtechnology.com"
]
```

**Result2:**

```
ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined index: email
```